# QTP/UFT Browser.Object throws error

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I have  **win 7 machine + UFT 11.53 + IE8**

I am unable to access

```
Browser("browser").Object
```

It throws "General error". However I am able to access

```
Browser("browser").Page("Page").Object
```

Anyone faced similar issue? It used to work fine before. Not sure what the exact issue is!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a logic issue as i said in my comments. Somehow there were 2 BHOManager.dll in the machine which was causing this issue. Removing them and repairing QTP made it work fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's invalid line of script what it's the need to use this command ?

you can use :

```
Browser("browser").Page("Page").Object.click()
X = Browser("browser").Page("Page").Object.getRoProperity()
Y = Browser("browser").Page("Page").Object.getToProperity()
...... etc.
```

also if the UFT not recoginized the objects close the browser and UFT

then open IE8 try to check "UFT-BHO manager if it enabled or not"
then open UFT and try again.

Comment: I know sir. But badly i would like to access "Browser().object". Also this is not something invalid statement. The issue happens only in machine. Works fine in other machines with similar config. Uninstall and Reinstall also did not help! Thanks for your time sir.

Answer (score 0):

Could be something to do with the Object Repository. It might be worth trying to perform this via DP instead of via the OR.

Try something like:

```
Set Obj = Browser("micClass:=Browser").Object
```

I've not worked with QTP/UFT in over a year now so can't check if this works but worth a go.

Comment: It did not help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is the need to save the browser in object script ?

i think if you try to fine something in the browser without OR you need to use descriptive programming :

```
Dim oDesc        'Description Object
Dim colObject    'Object Collection

Set oDesc = Description.Create
oDesc( "micclass" ).value = "Link"
oDesc( "x" ).value = 51  '51, not "51".

Set colObject = Browser( "title:=Google").Page("title:=Google").ChildObjects( oDesc )

'Will return 1
MsgBox colObject.Count

'Will return Images
For x = 0 to colObject.Count - 1
    MsgBox colObject(x).GetROProperty("innertext")
Next
```

--- Or add it directly to Object repository with unique value like HTML_ID or URL or href or class .........